# laravel Access forbidden error when trying to access url of /anything:anything syntax

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp

I have installed Laravel with Xampp server on Windows 7 successfully  .

I tried to add routes url and it works fine.

I want to display a MySQL table values on localhost 
So I make a model

```
class data extends Model
{
protected   $table = 'Data'; 
}
```

and a controller class and inside this controller class this method to display MySQL table

```
   public function show($id)
   {
   $data = Data::where('service_id', $service_id)->select ('price' ); 
   return view('greeting')->with('data',$data); 
   }
```

And I add a route to display my web page showing my table data .

but I get this error

**Access forbidden!**
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
**Error 403**

Although I haven't this error yesterday. but today I totally failed!!

I has observed that I get this error  when  I try to access any url likes this  syntax
 **/anything:anything** e.g: 
/one/public/Motors:1               /one/public/planes:1

but no problem when I use no parameterized query.

Comment: Obviously some kind of permissions problem. Did you try setting 777 permissions (recursively) on your project folder in *htdocs*?

Comment: I am working on Windows 7

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm sure there is an equivalent of doing this for Windows 7 if you look it up.

Comment: Okay , but observe also  that it works fine , except with database

Comment: Right. Which line of code throws the error exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change routes to the following and problem solved.
So I have to browse my page as **pagename/id instead of pagename:id**

```
   Route::get('pagename/{id}',array('uses' =>'MyclassController@MethodName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
public function show($id){$data = Data::where('service_id','=', $service_id)->select ('price' ); return view('greeting')->with('data',$data); }
```

Comment: Same problem . it's not matter of query as I think.

Comment: Have you a query without parameter,  I observed  /anything:any in my url gives that error!!